# problema con multer en node y restify

Tags: javascript, nodejs, multer

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en donde necesito subir una imagen y almacenar un registro de la ubicación de esta imagen en la BD. EN el lado del servidor utilizo nodejs con restify y mysql, para cargar las imágenes estoy utilizando multer en node js, este es el codigo:

```
                const multer = require('multer');


            const storage = multer.diskStorage({
                destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, '/storage/imgs')
                },
                filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                //   cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
                cb(null, file.originalname)
                }
            })
            const limits = {
                fileSize : 4000000
            }

            //fileFilter function controls which files should be uploaded. req = request being made. file = contains file info. cb = callback function to tell multer when we are done filtering the file. send back an error message to the client with cb.
            const fileFilter =(req, file, cb) => {
                //if the file is not a jpg, jpeg, or png file, do not upload it multer; reject it.
                if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
                    return cb(new Error('File must be of type JPG, JPEG, or PNG and nore more than 2MB in size'))
                }
                //undefined = nothing went wrong; true = that is true, nothing went wrong, accept the upload.
                cb(undefined, true)
            }
            //set up the multer middleware
            const upload = multer({
                storage: storage,
                limits: limits,
                fileFilter: fileFilter
                // filename: filename
            })

            module.exports= upload;
```

y este es el método en donde llamo a upload

```
let _insert = async function (req, res, next){
            try{
            upload.single('detalle_comercio_adherido');
            //     const { params } = req;
            //     let result = await comAdhServices.insertComAdh(params);

                // if(result === null){
                //     res.json(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
                //     res.end();
                //     return;
                // }
                // res.json(httpStatus.CREATED, result[0]);
                // res.end();
                
            }catch(err){
                res.send(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, JSON.stringify({Error: httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Message: constants.Error.INTERNALERROR}) );
            }
        };
```

lamentablemente no me entrega ningún error del porque no se sube la imagen, utilizo postman para realizar las pruebas pero el problema es que la imagen no se sube

Comment: Puedes agregar un `debugger` o algo por favor

Comment: upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    }
 
    // Everything went fine.
  })

Comment: upload is not a function

Comment: le agrego el .single y queda dando vueltas